# Lagrange multiplier, different results depending on when to take the derivatives.

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, statistical-mechanics

In statistical physics, one finds the probability distribution $\rho[q]$ that maximizes the entropy $S$

$$
S=-k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q]\ln \rho[q]\tag{1}
$$

under the constraints:

$$
\begin{align}
\overline{E}&=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}E[q]\rho[q] \tag{2}\\ 
1&=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\rho[q] \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

by using the method of the Lagrange multipliers:

$$
\mathcal{L}= \left( \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right) + \lambda \left(-1+ \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( - \overline{E} + \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right) \tag{4}
$$

---

To obtain the Gibbs measure, one must find the stationary action

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \rho[q]}=0
$$

I would like to know if my approach to it is valid. Let me start:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho[q]} \left[ \left( -k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right) + \lambda \left(-1+ \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( - \overline{E} + \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right) \right] =0 \\
&\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho[q]} \left[ \left( -k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right) + \lambda \left( \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right) \right] =0 \\
& \frac{\partial }{\partial \rho[q]} \left( k_B  \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right)  = \frac{\partial }{\partial \rho[q]}  \left[ \lambda \left( \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right)  \right]\\
& \left( k_B  \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right)  =  \lambda \left( \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right) +C\\
& S  =  \lambda +C  + \beta \overline{E} \\
& S  =  \ln Z + \beta \overline{E} 
\end{align}
$$

where we define $\ln Z = \lambda+C$.

---

I struggle with my derivation because it seems like there is an arbitrary choice to make. For instance, if I would have instead done this:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho[q]} \left[ \left( -k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right) + \lambda \left(-1+ \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( - \overline{E} + \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right) \right] =0 \\
&\left( -k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right) + \lambda \left(-1+ \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} p[q]   \right) + \beta \left( - \overline{E} + \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} E[q] \rho[q] \right)  +C =0 \\
&\left( -k_B \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} \rho[q] \ln \rho[q] \right) + \lambda \left(-1+ 1  \right) + \beta \left( - \overline{E} + \overline{E} \right)  +C =0 \\
&S + C =0 
\end{align}
$$

Why different results if I simply change the order in which I make the replacements? Which, if any, is correct?

Comment: What does $\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\rho[q]}$ actually mean? For differentiation you always need a variable with respect to which you differentiate. It is not clear what the $q$ in $\rho[q]$ is. Can we leave it away and write $\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial\rho}$?

Comment: @amsmath In the proof on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics) the $\rho[q]$ are written as $p_i$ and the derivative is taken as $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \rho_i}$. Not sure, but maybe it is satisfactory?

Comment: Aha, so each $\rho[q]$ is a separate variable. So, let's not write $\rho[q]$ because $q$ also appears in the sum. Lets write $\rho[r]$ instead. Now, you have to differentiate, e.g., $\sum_q\rho[q]\ln\rho[q]$ with respect to $\rho[r]$ for a fixed $r\in\mathbb Q$. Then for all $q\neq r$ in the sum the derivative is zero because for $\rho[r]$ they are constants. So, we are left with $\rho[r]\ln\rho[r]$. Here, we use the product rule. The derivative is $1\cdot\ln\rho[r] + \rho[r]\cdot \frac 1{\rho[r]} = \ln\rho[r] + 1$. Got it?

Comment: @amsmath I do understand this part, but what I am stuggling with is to understand why $\partial \overline{E}/ \partial \rho[r]$ is not equal to $\frac{\partial }{\partial \rho[r]} \sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} E[q]\rho[q]$. Since $\overline{E}=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}} E[q]\rho[q]$, I would assume they should be?

Comment: Of course this is true. But now you do the same as before. As all $\rho[q]$ for $q\neq r$ are constants, the derivative of $\bar E$ is the derivative of $E[r]\rho[r]$, which is $E[r]$.

Comment: @amsmath But then you also derive the negative of this value, so you always get an entropy of 0. The term on the right is $\beta(-\overline{E}+\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}E[q]\rho[q])$ therefore its derivative is zero (you get $\beta(-E[r]+E[r])$. Same for the middle term; you get $\lambda(-1+1)$. Finally, $\rho[q]=0$, instead of the Gibbs measure of statistical physics.You only get the Gibbs measure if you assume the derivative $-\beta \overline{E}$, and $-\lambda 1$ is zero.

Comment: Nope. The derivative of $\bar E$ is zero because it's a constant.